# Is there a better way to communicate to the Raspberry pi via a phone?

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, kivy

The project I am currently working on uses the raspberry pi to host a webserver. So when ever anyone opens a website, the Raspberry pi interprets this and turns on or off the given module. Since this project's main goal is to be portable, there can't be any wifi connection, so the webserver is not going to work. Is there a better way to send signals via a phone to the Raspberry Pi?

*Note: can this be done with kivy language, is it is an python is a language i am famailiar with.*

**Excuse my English**

Comment: "Since this project's main goal is to be portable, there can't be any wifi connection". What do you mean by this? Why is a wifi connection not portable? Do you mean portable as in "runs on multiple operating systems" or as in "can be carried around"?

Comment: When others use it, this involves in connecting the raspberry pi to the wifi. This is something I don't understand on how to do in a user friendly way?

Comment: Maybe your phone has a Wifi hotspot that RasPi can connect to?

Comment: Current phones and RasPis both tend to have Bluetooth...

Comment: how can bluetooth help?

Answer (score 0):

You could try getting a GSM Module, and then hook it up to receive SMSs and then based on that you can have the GSM or connected Module wake up the web server, etc.

[Get GSM here](https://www.pishop.co.za/store/gsmgprsgnssbluetooth-hat-for-raspberry-pi)